# Gradle build ignores Jetbrains annotations

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Let's say we have the following test code:

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.junit.Test;

public class NullTest {

  @Test
  public void testNull() {
    doNothing(null);
  }

  private @NotNull String doNothing(@NotNull String value) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

The test will pass when running `gradle test` directly or if IDEA delegates the action to gradle.
But it will fail with `IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'value' must not be null` exception if it runs using IDEA runner (not delegated to gradle).

The question is: how to fail the test running it with gradle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution I have found is to apply [org.jetbrains.intellij](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin) plugin.
Because among other things this plugin "patches compile tasks to instrument code with nullability assertions".

```
  apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.intellij'

  intellij {
    instrumentCode = true
    downloadSources = false
  }
```

Comment: But this downloads 500MB+ jar at the moment :/

Comment: In a GitHub issue, [an employee of JetBrains suggests](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/issues/387#issuecomment-482792113) to write your own Gradle plugin based on [IntelliJInstrumentCodeTask](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/jetbrains/intellij/tasks/IntelliJInstrumentCodeTask.groovy). This might help with the size of the download.

Comment: Should this solution still work? I tried this, and made sure that assertions are enabled, but i couldn't get any assertions being thrown despite assigning null values to variables annotated with @NotNull

Comment: It does still work, the issue was that i was checking with `@NotNull` String bar = null;

But that can't be instrumented apparently, checking with the `@NotNull` annotation on the return value does work.

Comment: How to adapt this solution to Maven?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the following to your dependencies. It worked for me.

```
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0'
```

Comment: This helped me to get Gradle to stop failing a build, but I'm not sure that was precisely the question of the OP (which is why this answer may have been downvoted).

Answer (score 0):

With this code - no way, because you use annotations from org.jetbrains.annotations.*, that use only in intellij idea tests runner. For gradle, annotation @NotNull (or @Nullable) says nothing. Maven also doesn't see this annotation. I can advise you use Objects.requireNonNull(T obj) for null checking.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is very difficult to do because of the size of the project and team agreements. Anyway I hope to find the solution for the gradle.

Answer (score 0):

We found that Lombok's `@NonNull` works better. But you need to configure IDEA to prefer this one during nullability-related analysis and generation

Answer (score -1):

Adding the following dependency worked for me:

```
compile group: 'org.jetbrains', name: 'annotations', version: '15.0'
```

Run the 'dependencies' task & push the refresh button in Gradle.